# Using content_for inline in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in my layout

`<body class="<%= yield :body_class %>">`

Then in my view this works correctly:

`<% content_for(:body_class) do %>some-class<% end %>`

But this does not:

`<% content_for(:body_class) { 'some-class' } %>`

Does anyone know why?

Btw, this is Rails 2.3 with Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: I don't know why that doesn't work, but I do know what DOES work: `<% content_for :body_class, 'some-class' %>`

Comment: what about <% content_for(:body_class) { %> 'some-class' <% } %>

Comment: @mischa - that is awesome, like that solution better!  @DGM, that worked also.  So strange.

Comment: looking at your question again, I think it doesn't work because there is no 'output' to the template in your code. It seems you have to use `%>some-class<%` when you use the blocks. Or maybe `{ puts 'some-class' }` works. Anyway the way I suggested above is probably the preferred way if you just want to set a class dynamically.

Comment: Strangely, the `{ puts 'some-class' }` method doesn't work either, but DGM's link to the Railscast video sheds some light on it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the way blocks are captured into output buffers.  See http://railscasts.com/episodes/40-blocks-in-view  for more info.

Comment: Nice!  You get the green checkmark.  After watching that video I'm wishing Ruby blocks were not so complex, but I think you're right that is the root cause.

Comment: Rails 3 changed it a bit I think, and he also has a railscast on that.